# How to Calculating with variable height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, opc

For our Checkout with Magento I'm using the [Improved OPC design(css only)](https://www.h-o.nl/blog/improved_magento_one_page_checkout_design_css_only) from h-o.nl.

Each .opc-step-* has postion:absolute, but the #checkoutSteps has a static min-height. So every step does have another height for .opc-step-*

When customer have a lot of products to checkout the min-height from the div will be exceeded.

So I need to set the div height from .opc-step-* at the min-height of #checkoutSteps. That's going good. But it need to be 80 px more height. How to calculate divHeight + 80px ?

this is the function I have without the the calculation the opcheckout.js

```
gotoSection: function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {

        if (reloadProgressBlock) {
            this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
        }
        this.currentStep = section;
        var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
        sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
        this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);
        if(!reloadProgressBlock) {
            this.resetPreviousSteps();
        }
        jQuery("html, body").delay(10).animate({
            scrollTop: (
                jQuery("#opc-"+section).offset().top - jQuery('#header').height()
            )
        },
        50);
        var divHeight = jQuery("#checkout-step-"+ section).outerHeight( true );
        jQuery('#checkoutSteps').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it

```
jQuery('#checkoutSteps').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
```

change into:

```
jQuery('#checkoutSteps').css({'min-height':(divHeight+80)+'px'});
```